# How to avoid circular dependency in my scenario?

Tags: microservices, dependencies, dependency-management, circular-dependency, dependency-analysis

For example, I have a Business Intelligence (BI) microservice, it reads data from other microservices, and displays the data as a bar chart or some other styles.

My problem is, the BI microservice needs other microservices to register the display content and some rules, and the BI microservice reads and displays the data according the registered rules. So BI microservice calls other microservices and other microservices call BI microservice.

```
|-------| <--- register the display rule and get data method. -------- |------------|
| BI MS |                                                              | business MS|
|-------| ----call MS to get data according the method and rule -----> |------------|
```

How to resolve the cyclic dependency here? Should business microservice send an event to register the display rule?

Comment: How can BI perform analysis, if it has no understanding of the nature and sources of data? If it has, why register them?

Comment: @GregBurghardt could you please remove the spaces from your edit? [Microservice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) is mostly used as a single word.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that. I was on my mobile. Auto correct hasn't caught up with programmer jargon yet.

Comment: I've read the question several times and it's not clear to me why the other microservices need to call the BI. This seems a case where you either didn't decompose enough (there should be a shared microservices between bi and the others) or you decomposed too much (bi and the others are in fact the same logical entity but separated due to whatever reason).

Answer (score 3):

This is a data flow, not a logical dependency.

It should be fine, as long as BI MS does not make assumptions about API of other services (does not know about them). For that to work, display rules should contain enough information for BI to integrate with an arbitrary new service. If a display rule dictates from which endpoint to fetch the data, the actual service behind that endpoint stays irrelevant and BI MS *does not depend* on it.

The circular data flow has its own problems, in particular lifetime and availability of data and data sources may lead to deadlocks of various kinds, but the nature of BI implies, that those are not a concern (worst case, BI shows an incomplete graph).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really specified what behavior your BI micro service encapsulates. First, you'll need to determine what happens if the other micro services become unavailable. Does your BI micro service still function, but with stale data? If so, then I wouldn't worry about your current design. Let these things call each other as needed. If your BI service goes down because these other services go down, then you A) do have a circular dependency that needs solving; and B) you *don't* have micro services.

You also don't want the other services to go down because the BI micro service is unavailable. It's so hard to convey this, but `micro service != small`. Either consolidate all of these services into one, or introduce message queues in between these services. Each service reads from its own queue to do work. Publish messages on other queues to get those other services to do work. Message queues provide a buffer between services to limit the blast radius of an outage. The presumption here is that message queues are more stable than your services, so they should fail less often (the [smart endpoints and dumb pipes](https://medium.com/@nathankpeck/microservice-principles-smart-endpoints-and-dumb-pipes-5691d410700f) perspective suggested by Martin Fowler).

If you already have message queues, also consider requiring those other services to push all required data to your BI service before calling the BI service to do its job. Now your BI service has everything it needs.

There is nothing wrong with needing data from multiple services as long as you avoid a chain reaction of service calls just to get your BI service call to work. A micro service can store duplicate data, provided the data is relevant to itself. This is how micro services become independent, and this could be the key to breaking problematic dependencies between services.

Answer (score 0):

Really you need to provide more information on the actual calls. However this kind of circular dependency problem is not unusual with microservices.

Although ard to give you an exact answer without the details I find that most cases this comes down to not passing enough data in the messages that are sent to the microservices.

For example. Say you have a Stock microservice and an Order Micro Service. When you place an order for a product you need to check to see if it's in stock. but the stock service also checks to see if there are pending orders that need filling. So you get a circular call,

```
Order.Place(order) -> Stock.GetStock(itemId) -> Order.ListOrdersForItem(itemId)
```

This can lead to an infinite loop, or double counting etc. However if we send the full order instead of just itemIds then we have additional information of the orderId. Now GetStock(order) can keep track of which orders have stock assigned internally and not have to make the ListOrderForItem call.

Fat messages can reduce the "chattiness" of your microservices, as they don't have to make additional calls to fill in details they might need for the implementation of their calls and reduces the changes needed to interfaces when logic changes.

For example, say we add a second warehouse, the stock calculation might now depend on the customer location. But since we are sending the full `Order` which includes the customer details the interface doesn't change and no extra calls to a Customer microservice are required.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a microservice is that it should have at least some major independent functionality of its own. It should be deployable and available independently of other services. A single microservice should correspond in scale with an "application".

I get the impression that practitioners in "microservices" are largely repeating the same errors in thinking as were often made about object-oriented design, except this time as farce instead of tragedy.

The fundamental pattern of the error is to keep recursively applying a divide-and-conquer strategy to a design problem that requires a solution to have all-round integrity and cooperative internal workings.

If you have a reporting facility that relies on many other microservices and has no independent functionality of its own, then it is by definition not a microservice but an integration layer (which cannot survive without the providers which comprise it).

Data can flow between microservices, but there shouldn't be a requirement that this is a real-time interaction for all primary functionality.

The safest guidance for designing microservices is that a single development team should handle a single microservice. In other words, neither a sole practitioner nor a team manager would ever be responsible for multiple microservices, only a manager of managers would ever have oversight over two microservices.

There may be exceptions, such as where one developer with a low workload and two simple *and unrelated* microservices ends up handling both, or where special (not typical) deployment and availability requirements means something that could be one microservice is split in two (and the costs and overheads of such splitting borne) even though it is actually designed and overseen as one.

But you get the gist about how many microservices the typical individual developer should be dealing with - one, either as a sole developer, or as part of a team of developers who look after that one.

Comment: What is the answer? Squash all the stuff?

Comment: @Basilevs, the answer is for him to stop fussing and just write it as one service, which it is.

Comment: One interesting point here is that it is strange for BI not to be aware of all the data sources. How can it perform analysis, if it has no vision in the nature and source of data?

Comment: There are many microservices in OPs context, business MS on the diagram is potentially 10s of them.

Comment: @Basilevs, most BI doesn't need to be real-time or anywhere close to it, and can require a lot of processing, so usually reporting just gets done from a single bulk copy of business data. And if you've got 10s of microservices, you're probably just looking at a needlessly complicated architecture, and probably with no transactional consistency or consistent method of backup and recovery.

Comment: I'm talking not about perfromance, but about architecture - BI should by nature be aware of data sources it consumes. It makes no sense to have multiple dynamic data sources.
10s of microservices could be justified by reasons outside of question scope - obviously OP did not create them for BI.